# sqlite to postgres rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, null, strftime

I'm trying to deploy my rails app on heroku, but I can't seem to have it recognize my databases/tables as even existing. For some reason, I seem to have translated the problem back locally as well, and now I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass):
```

When I try to execute this command:

```
<%= result.start_time.strftime("%a at %I:%M%p") %>
```

This worked previously. now I am trying to run it locally again and it isn't working.

I THINK the problem is that there is no database "results" being recognized, so we are trying to run strftime on a "nil" object. However, I have no clue how to get it to recognize the db, and have been fooling with it for hours. The development.sqlite db is still under the "/db/" folder, and rake db:reset doesn't seem to work. I use the SQLite database browser, and i can SEE the results table. It makes NO sense.

please help.

David

Answer (score 2):

this particular problem is not about db.

Try this:

```
<%= result.start_time.strftime("%a at %I:%M%p") if result.start_time %>
```

It means that start_time field is blank. So results table presents, but particular field data doesn't exist.

Maybe, while you were transfering from sqlite3 to postgres `DateTime` fields weren't transfered succesfully.

Comment: I'd agree with you, but once I got rid of the strftime statements completely, a new error poppped, up, saying "can't convert nil into String". This was because I tried to do "result.id.to_s" so this says to me that NOTHING was converted over.